# Is ChartFX 6.2 compatible with Vista and Windows 7

Tags: winforms, chartfx

Does anyone have any success with WinForms ChartFX 6.2 on Vista or Windows? I'm after a sanity check that it's not just our code. If it's a known issue I can say that upgrading is the only solution.

Currently we get an exception in the Scatter Chart when adding annotations, it looks like it's in the GDI, but the exception can't be caught or handled and is slightly intermittent.

SoftwareFX forums have said that it should work.

Comment: I'm currently developing and running chartfx 6.2 in a windows 7 x64 environment with no issues so far.